# Changing the forecolor and backcolor of text in a textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net, textbox, background-color, foreground

I'm making a C++ code editor application using VB.NET. I'd like to change the color of the keywords as the user types it. Also I'm looking for a way to highlight some lines of the code.

Is there a way to change the forecolor and backcolour of a piece of text inside a textbox or a rich textbox?

Comment: Not possible, RichTextBox is required as long as you keep to standard controls.

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not really know what you want to do so here are some options.

If you want a step by step tutorial on how to write a syntax highlighting control, you can read these articles:

1. [Syntax Highlighting in RichTextBox Part 1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/duncanharris/syntaxhighlightinrichtextboxp112012005050840am/syntaxhighlightinrichtextboxp1.aspx) and [Part 2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/duncanharris/SyntaxHighlightInRichTextBoxP212012005044912AM/SyntaxHighlightInRichTextBoxP2.aspx).
2. [Syntax Highlighting in RichTextBox using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kirtan007/2511/)

For a basic syntax highlighting control written in VB.NET, see this article: [Color Syntax Control (VB.NET)](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=5176).

There are two very good options if you want a fully-fledged syntax highlighting control. These are:

1. [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) for WinForms and;
2. [AvalonEdit](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx) for WPF.

   - There is a tutorial on [Using AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx) on CodeProject so be sure to check that out as well.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use RTF in the richtextbox control.

From http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm

```
{\f1\cb1\cf2 This is colored text. The background is color
1 and the foreground is color 2.}
```

Comment: How do we do it in C#/VB.NET?

Comment: @Arjun Via .Rtf see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the normal foreground and background properties of a textbox cannot help, and you need to use rich text and format that manually (through text coloring and highlighting algorithms).