# How to Change text color?

Tags: string, c#-4.0, text-coloring

Hi
I am using following code to append text and I want to change the color of newly appended text how is it possible

```
if (strMessage.IndexOf("pvt|") == -1)
{
   string[] temp = strMessage.Split(new string[] {"&^:^&"}, tringSplitOptions.None);
   strMessage = temp[0] + "(" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm tt") + ")" + ":" + emp[1];
   txtLog.AppendText(strMessage + "\r\n");
}
```

Please help..

Comment: Is this ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms, what?

Comment: Strings in .Net have no concept of color, so there can be no answer.  If you are going to accept an answer, please add the appropriate tags/text to your question to say what context you plan to use/read the text in.  What is `txtLog`, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Where is the text being displayed? It appears that it goes to a [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx), but that's just an assumption.

Changing the color of individual chunks of text within a normal TextBox is not possible. You can change the *entire* TextBox's forecolor by setting its `ForeColor` property.

```
txtLog.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

To change pieces of it individually, then you will need to use a different textbox, such as shown in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974479/changing-the-forecolor-and-backcolor-of-text-in-a-textbox/5280895#5280895).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that txtLog is a text file you would have to encode ascii control characters into stream and have an editor that read them.  This [link](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ansi.php#AnsiColor) might help.